# What is the proper method of printing Python Exceptions?

Tags: python, exception

```
        except ImportError as xcpt:
            print "Import Error: " + xcpt.message
```

Gets you a deprecation warning in 2.6 because message is going away.
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272138/baseexception-message-deprecated-in-python-2-6)

How should you be dealing with ImportError?  (Note, this is a built-in exception, not one of my making....)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The correct approach is

```
xcpt.args
```

Only the `message` attribute is going away.  The exception will continue to exist and it will continue to have arguments.

Read this: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/ which has some rational for removing the `messages` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print the exception:

```
print "Couldn't import foo.bar.baz: %s" % xcpt
```

Exceptions have a `__str__` method defined to create a readable version of themselves.  I wouldn't bother with "Import Error:" since the exception will provide that itself.  If you add text to the exception, make it be something you know based on the code you were trying to execute.

Comment: When I do
print xcpt, I get  "No module named tribes.models" which does not give me the exception title, even though it is implicit in the message.