# Python: Getting the error message of an exception

Tags: python, django, exception

In python 2.6.6, how can I capture the error message of an exception.

IE:

```
response_dict = {} # contains info to response under a django view.
try:
    plan.save()
    response_dict.update({'plan_id': plan.id})
except IntegrityError, e: #contains my own custom exception raising with custom messages.
    response_dict.update({'error': e})
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict), mimetype="application/json")
```

This doesnt seem to work. I get:

```
IntegrityError('Conflicts are not allowed.',) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: "This doesnt seem to work." - what should it do and doesn't do?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Pass it through `str()` first.

```
response_dict.update({'error': str(e)})
```

Also note that certain exception classes may have specific attributes that give the exact error.

Answer (score 3):

Everything about `str` is correct, yet another answer: an `Exception` instance has `message` attribute, and you may want to use it (if your customized `IntegrityError` doesn't do something special):

```
except IntegrityError, e: #contains my own custom exception raising with custom messages.
    response_dict.update({'error': e.message})
```

Comment: The BaseException.message attribute has been deprecated since Python 2.6. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272138/baseexception-message-deprecated-in-python-2-6

Answer (score 3):

You should use `unicode` instead of `string` if you are going to translate your application.

BTW, Im case you're using json because of an Ajax request, I suggest you to send errors back with `HttpResponseServerError` rather than `HttpResponse`:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseServerError
response_dict = {} # contains info to response under a django view.
try:
    plan.save()
    response_dict.update({'plan_id': plan.id})
except IntegrityError, e: #contains my own custom exception raising with custom messages.
    return HttpResponseServerError(unicode(e))

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response_dict), mimetype="application/json")
```

and then manage errors in your Ajax procedure.
If you wish I can post some sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you raise error like this

```
raise someError("some error message")
```

and 'e' is catched error instance

str(e) returns:

```
[ErrorDetail(string='some error message', code='invalid')]
```

but if you want "some error message" only

```
e.detail
```

will gives you that (actually gives you a list of str which includes "some error message")

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
def getExceptionMessageFromResponse( oResponse ):
    #
    '''
    exception message is burried in the response object,
    here is my struggle to get it out
    '''
    #
    l = oResponse.__dict__['context']
    #
    oLast = l[-1]
    #
    dLast = oLast.dicts[-1]
    #
    return dLast.get( 'exception' )
```