# Change message of a caught Python exception (at least on Python 3.x, hopefully on 2.5+ too)

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

Quite similar to [the question "Getting the error message of an exception"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460669/python-getting-the-error-message-of-an-exception) except that I don't want to get the message out of the exception, I want to SET it.

Until recently, I thought I had a working solution involving changing `my_exception.args` but i've just reached the limits trying to play with SyntaxError.

A bit of (bad) code to get things ready :

```
def get_exc(code):
    """Quick & dirty code to get exceptions."""
    try:
        exec(code)
    except:
        return sys.exc_info()
    assert False
```

Then, getting a NameError exception, printing it, updating it, re-printing it, re-raising it : it seems like it works properly :

```
code = "foo = bar" # NameError("name 'bar' is not defined",)
error = get_exc(code)
type_, val, bt = error
print("Error", str(error), repr(error))
print("val", str(val), repr(val))
print("args", str(val.args), repr(val.args))
val.args = ("Setting val.args", )
print("Error", str(error), repr(error))
print("val", str(val), repr(val))
raise val
```

I can see the `Setting val.args` message in the exception representation, its string conversion and when I raise it.

Trying to do the same with various other types of errors seems to be fine except for SyntaxError. First thing first, the exception has a few more attributes including `msg`. Let's try to get the exception, print it, update it (both via `msg` and `args`), re-print it, re-raising it.

```
code = "return" # SyntaxError("'return' outside function", ('<string>', 1, 0, None))
error = get_exc(code)
type_, val, bt = error
print("Error", str(error), repr(error))
print("val", str(val), repr(val))
val.args = ("Setting val.args", val.args[1])
val.msg = "Setting val.msg"
print("Error", str(error), repr(error))
print("val", str(val), repr(val))
raise val
```

`repr` displays `Setting val.args` while `str` and `raise` display `Setting val.msg`. How odd!

This leads to a few (quite related) questions :

- why do we have the same information ("invalid syntax") in two places (`args` and `msg`).
- what is the actual working and recommanded way to update the message ? At the moment, I'm assuming something along the lines of "change `args` and if there is a `msg` attribute, change it too" but I do not find this very beautiful nor am I sure that it will work for other types of Exceptions I might have not considered.

Additional reference : I've looked for a solution in [PEP 352 - Required Superclass for Exceptions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0352/)  but I didn't find what I needed.

**Edit:**

To confirm accepted answer : `print(val.msg is val.args[0]) # True`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.args` is an attribute of `BaseException`, and is usually just passed all of the arguments to the exception.

`.msg` is the first argument, and is an attribute of `SyntaxError`. It references the same string as given in `.args`, if any.

[Source link.](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/exceptions.c#L1261)

> what is the actual working and recommanded way to update the message ?

To not do so at all. Most of the time, one should just raise a new, chained exception.

There is also no way to do this for an arbitrary class, since they can have effectively any layout.