# How to serialize an Exception

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, exception, serialization

When I try to serialize an exception using `json.dump`, I get errors like

```
TypeError: IOError('socket error', error(61, 'Connection refused')) is not JSON serializable
```

and

```
TypeError: error(61, 'Connection refused') is not JSON serializable
```

The `__dict__` field of exceptions is `{}` (this is why [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3768895/850781) does not help me: the answers there assume that `__dict__` contains all the necessary information, they also assume that I have control over the class to be serialized).

Is there something more intelligent that saving `str(exn)`?

I would prefer a human-readable text representation (not `pickle`).

PS. Here is what I came up with:

```
def exception_as_dict(ex):
    return dict(type=ex.__class__.__name__,
                errno=ex.errno, message=ex.message,
                strerror=exception_as_dict(ex.strerror)
                if isinstance(ex.strerror,Exception) else ex.strerror)

json.dumps(exception_as_dict(err),indent=2)
{
  "errno": "socket error", 
  "type": "IOError", 
  "strerror": {
    "errno": 61, 
    "type": "error", 
    "strerror": "Connection refused"
  }
}
```

Comment: You could capture the exception object and pickle it? You can pass the pickled data as a binary payload in a JSON object.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: I would prefer a human-readable text representation. Your comment suggests that the answer is "no". Thanks.

Comment: You didn't make that clear. It seemed like you wanted some way of communicating execptions remotely. Anyway, you'll have to look for some 3rd party library, or write your own custom parser to deconstruct or construct the object to/from JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a class JSON serializable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable)

Comment: @Leon: not really a dupe: `__dict__` is useless in `Exception`.

Comment: Just pass the exception through `str()` see the original post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4460669/python-getting-the-error-message-of-an-exception?lq=1

Answer (score 17):

You can use `exc_info` with `traceback` as below:

```
import traceback
import sys
try:
    raise KeyError('aaa!!!')
except Exception as e:
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()
    print(''.join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info)))
```

Answer (score 10):

Exceptions can not be pickled (by default), you have two options:

1. Use Python's built in format_exc() and serialize the formatted string.
2. Use [`tblib`](https://github.com/ionelmc/python-tblib)

With the latter, you can pass wrapped exceptions and also reraise them later.

```
import tblib.pickling_support
tblib.pickling_support.install()
import pickle, sys 

def inner_0():
    raise Exception('fail')

def inner_1():
    inner_0()

def inner_2():
    inner_1()

try:
    inner_2()
except:
    s1 = pickle.dumps(sys.exc_info())
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it in case this also helps someone else:

```
except Exception as error:
    exc_info = sys.exc_info()

    sExceptionInfo = ''.join(traceback.format_exception(*exc_info))

    exc_type, exc_value, exc_context = sys.exc_info()

    rHttpResponse = JsonResponse( 
        {
            "status": "error",
            "type": exc_type.__name__,
            "description": str(exc_value),
            "details": sExceptionInfo 
        }
    )

return rHttpResponse
```

The goal being where any Exception is serialized to the actual Exception with:

- "type" being the actual Exception class name (e.g. AttributeError)
- "description" being the short detail (e.g. 'str' attribute has no attribute '_meta')
- "details" being the traceback list of code, file, line number, call stack.
  The end result is something a UI can determine how much to show to give the user some smart error message to capture and send to a help desk.

My rule I follow is to always return HTTP 200 and indicate in the response JSON if it was successful or not to allow for the caller to handle it.

When not in a debug mode, the traceback could be suppressed, but the idea is to give enough info so when a user calls the help desk they have something more than "it doesn't work".