# Python - How to print error with JSON format

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm new to Python, but as much as I search - I don't find a "jsonfiy" method for printing an error to the logs.

the way I'm printing today:

```
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e))
    print(e)
    print(traceback.format_exc())
```

This way I get all needed data from the exception, but I must represent it in a JSON format.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to serialize an Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240549/how-to-serialize-an-exception)

Comment: Take a look at the [pprint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) library. Using `pprint.pprint(<dict_like_var>)` will present the variable content in a nice way.

Comment: @aberkb, thanks for your suggestion, but I don't find a "jsonfiy" way to print it. JSON is must here in order to make searches within the error logs

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer to my question, using [python-json-logger](https://pypi.org/project/python-json-logger/), in my case I used it within Flask app, so the way to configure logger to use JSON format is this:

```
formatter = jsonlogger.JsonFormatter('%(asctime) %(levelname) %(message)')
app.logger.handlers[0].setFormatter(formatter)
```

Then I used app logger to log an error with JSON format like this:

```
except Exception as e:
    app.logger.error({"error": type(e).__name__, "message": e, "at": traceback.format_exc()})
```