# AWS create_state_machine -

Tags: aws-step-functions

I have python code that is supposed to be accepting parameter and creating state machine.  I keep getting this error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to marshal response: Object of type StateMachineAlreadyExists is not JSON serializable",
  "errorType": "Runtime.MarshalError",
  "requestId": "67e700e5-57c7-46c2-bcb5-da12835c3f39",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

My json is valid as per jsonlint.com.  I have to assume the issue is how I am passing it to the create_state_machine call but I have tried many things - so far without success.

here is my python for the create - being executed in a lambda (method shrunk for brevity)

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    event_body = event["body"]

    sf = boto3.client('stepfunctions',
                    aws_access_key_id='<<<accesskey>>>',
                    aws_secret_access_key='<<<secretkey>>>',
                    region_name = '<<<region>>>')
    response_body = {}
    try:
        response_body = sf.create_state_machine(name="connexStepPuller",
                                            definition=json.dumps(event_body),
                                            roleArn="<<<rolearn<<<")
    except Exception as err:
        response_body["status_code"] = 500
        print('error: %s', err)
        response_body["error"] = err
        response_body["stateMachineArn"] = None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a couple of problems here.

First, is that Python Exceptions are not serializable as JSON. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45240549/how-to-serialize-an-exception) provides some solutions for you to consider. This is why you get the "Unable to marshall response" error.

Second, you are calling [CreateStateMachine](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_CreateStateMachine.html) with a static value for Name. So you can't run this code more than once in an account. The exception you are experiencing, [StateMachineAlreadyExists](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/apireference/API_CreateStateMachine.html#API_CreateStateMachine_Errors), indicates that:

```
A state machine with the same name but a different definition or role ARN already exists.
```

Comment: thank you - where did you see StateMachineAlreadyExists, in the error?  I thought I had checked for the name already being there - I hard-coded the name to get it working before making that configurable - again thank you

Comment: It’s in the text of the errorMessage you shared