# Why doesn't it work to append information in the exception message?

Tags: python, exception

Why doesn't this work?

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    e.message += ', you fool!'
    raise
```

The modified message is not used, even though it remains on the exception instance.  Is there a working pattern for the above?  Behaviour should be like my current workaround below:

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    args = e.args
    if not args:
        arg0 = ''
    else:
        arg0 = args[0]
    arg0 += ', you fool!'
    e.args = (arg0,) + args[1:]
    raise
```

I'm aware of [exception chaining](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) in python3, it looks nice but unfortunately doesn't work in python2.  So what is the usual recipe for re-raising an exception in python2?

*Note*:  Because of the warnings and caveats mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info), I don't want to dig up the traceback and create a new exception but rather **re-raise the existing exception** instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing `e.args` is the only way to do this.  The [implementation for `BaseException.__str__`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/6f6e56bb10aa/Objects/exceptions.c#l100) only considers the `args` tuple, it doesn't look at `message` at all:

```
static PyObject * 
BaseException_str(PyBaseExceptionObject *self)
{
    PyObject *out;

    switch (PyTuple_GET_SIZE(self->args)) { 
    case 0:
        out = PyString_FromString("");
        break;
    case 1:
        out = PyObject_Str(PyTuple_GET_ITEM(self->args, 0));
        break;
    default:
        out = PyObject_Str(self->args);
        break;
    } 

    return out;
}
```

This shouldn't be too unexpected, since [`BaseException.message` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272138/baseexception-message-deprecated-in-python-2-6) since Python 2.6.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's going to be a better solution than your workaround. `ZeroDivisionError` doesn't use the `message` property to build its output, so modifying that will have no effect.

If you're specifically catching a ZeroDivisionError it should always have a single argument so the following more succinct version will work:

```
try:
    1/0
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    e.args = (e.args[0] + ', you fool!',)
    raise
```

If you check the properties of ZeroDivisionError, all it has are `args` and `message` and it doesn't use `message` so short of creating a new error, modifying args is pretty much the only possible solution.