# How to get exception message in Python properly

Tags: python, exception

What is the best way to get exceptions' messages from components of standard library in Python?

I noticed that in some cases you can get it via `message` field like this:

```
try:
  pass
except Exception as ex:
  print(ex.message)
```

but in some cases (for example, in case of socket errors) you have to do something like this:

```
try:
  pass
except socket.error as ex:
  print(ex)
```

I wondered is there any standard way to cover most of these situations?

Comment: You're conflating two different things - `except Foo as bar:` is the same as `except Foo, bar:` (except the former is newer, and will continue to work in 3.x), whether the error comes with a `message` attribute or not is separate.

Comment: @FrozenHeart Are you asking whether accessing `.message` for an error is standard way or not?

Comment: your second example with `print(msg)` is just a shortcut for `print(str(msg))`

Comment: @Anand S Kumar Yep. Will it work in any case?

Comment: I believe accessing `message` is deprecated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1272138/baseexception-message-deprecated-in-python-2-6

Answer (score 184, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for the built-in errors](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html), you'll see that most `Exception` classes assign their first argument as a `message` attribute. Not all of them do though.

Notably,`EnvironmentError` (with subclasses `IOError` and `OSError`) has a first argument of `errno`, second of `strerror`. There is no `message`... `strerror` is roughly analogous to what would normally be a `message`.

More generally, subclasses of `Exception` can do whatever they want. They may or may not have a `message` attribute. Future built-in `Exception`s may not have a `message` attribute. Any `Exception` subclass imported from third-party libraries or user code may not have a `message` attribute.

I think the proper way of handling this is to identify the specific `Exception` subclasses you want to catch, and then catch only those instead of everything with an `except Exception`, then utilize whatever attributes that specific subclass defines however you want.

If you must `print` something, I think that printing the caught `Exception` itself is most likely to do what you want, whether it has a `message` attribute or not.

You could also check for the message attribute if you wanted, like this, but I wouldn't really suggest it as it just seems messy:

```
try:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    # Just print(e) is cleaner and more likely what you want,
    # but if you insist on printing message specifically whenever possible...
    if hasattr(e, 'message'):
        print(e.message)
    else:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there any particular reason to use `str(ex)` instead of just `ex`?

Comment: @FrozenHeart - `print()` automatically calls `str()` for you. There's no reason to manually call it yourself, although it's harmless since calling `str()` on a string will just return the string itself.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I think there might be issues with `str()` if message is of type `unicode`.

Answer (score 77):

To improve on the answer provided by [@artofwarfare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901641/artofwarfare), here is what I consider a neater way to check for the `message` attribute and print it or print the `Exception` object as a fallback.

```
try:
    pass 
except Exception as e:
    print getattr(e, 'message', repr(e))
```

The call to `repr` is optional, but I find it necessary in some use cases.

---

**Update #1:**

Following the comment by [@MadPhysicist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2988730/mad-physicist), here's a proof of why the call to `repr` might be necessary. Try running the following code in your interpreter:

```
try:
    raise Exception 
except Exception as e:
    print(getattr(e, 'message', repr(e)))
    print(getattr(e, 'message', str(e)))
```

The `repr(e)` line will print `Exception()` and the `str(e)` line will print an empty string.

---

**Update #2:**

Here is a demo with specifics for Python 2.7 and 3.5: https://gist.github.com/takwas/3b7a6edddef783f2abddffda1439f533

Comment: `getattr` throws an exception if the object passed in doesn't have the requested attribute. If you wanted to do something like that, I think you should use the optional third argument for `getattr`, like this: `print getattr(e, 'message', e)`. Debatably better than what I did. Another option would be `print(e.message if hasattr(e, 'message') else e)`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: Interestingly, I had just discovered that and was coming to update this answer. It works fine in Python 2. The issue you raise is with Python 3.

Comment: Right. Somehow, it seemed to work earlier. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You would almost certainly want `str` instead of `repr`.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I have updated the answer with a proof of why you "might" need `repr`.

Comment: I don't have an interpreter nearby , could you show a sample output please ?

Comment: Your example is actually perfect for my case: http://ideone.com/jJUoyC. You want to see the message as being empty, not the constructor for your object.

Comment: Yes. You should try this: https://gist.github.com/takwas/3b7a6edddef783f2abddffda1439f533

Comment: Compared to `str`, `repr` just adds the class name. Instead of using `repr`, I'd propose to use `print('{e.__class__.__name__}: {e}'.format(e=e))`. The print output is cleaner and adheres to the output of raise itself.

Comment: Based on the above, I found the most useful for me to be `'{e.__class__.__module__}.{e.__class__.__name__}: {e}'`

Comment: Thanks!! `repr(e)` was for now the only solution that helped me print at least a minimal amount of info on an error I catch in some particular circumstance. `repr(e)` yields `KeyError(0,)` (which is what the error is), while `str(e)` or `e.message` yielded only `0` or nothing at all respectively.

Comment: This is clean, nice one-liner

Answer (score 13):

I too had the same problem. Digging into this I found that the Exception class has an `args` attribute, which captures the arguments that were used to create the exception. If you narrow the exceptions that except will catch to a subset, you should be able to determine how they were constructed, and thus which argument contains the message.

```
try:
   # do something that may raise an AuthException
except AuthException as ex:
   if ex.args[0] == "Authentication Timeout.":
      # handle timeout
   else:
      # generic handling
```

Comment: **This is the most general answer.** Consult https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException

Answer (score 7):

```
from traceback import format_exc


try:
    fault = 10/0
except ZeroDivision:
    print(format_exc())
```

Another possibility is to use the format_exc() method from the traceback module.

Answer (score -3):

I had the same problem. I think the best solution is to use log.exception, which will automatically print out stack trace and error message, such as:

```
import logging as log

try:
    pass
    log.info('Success')
except:
    log.exception('Failed')
```

Comment: What is `log`? I just tried `import log` on Python 2.7.13 and got a message that there is no module with that name. Is it something you added via `pip` or was it added in a newer version of python (I know, I know, I need to update to Python 3... I'll do that just as soon as CentOS stops shipping with Python 2 by default...)

Comment: He/She is probably using the logging module from python and then instantiating a logger as a log variable.
`import logging`\n
`log = logging.getLogger(__name__)`