# Where does pytest.skip('Output string') get printed?

Tags: python

I have the following code in a python module called test_me.py:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def test_me():
     if condition:
        pytest.skip('Test Message')

def test_func(test_me):
    assert ...
```

The output looks like:

```
tests/folder/test_me.py::test_me SKIPPED
```

Question: Where does 'Test Message' get printed or output?  I can't see or find it anywhere.

Comment: I was going to refer you to the official documentation, but it doesn't appear to explain this.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel exactly.  It was from the original docs I got the idea to use this feature but it doesn't seem to work as I expected.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Pytest documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/reorganize-docs/new-docs/user/skipping.html), you can use the `-rs` flag to show it.

```
$ pytest -rs
======================== test session starts ========================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ...
collected 1 item                                                    

test_sample.py s                                              [100%]

====================== short test summary info ======================
SKIPPED [1] test_sample.py:5: Test Message
======================== 1 skipped in 0.02s =========================
```

```py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture()
def test_me():
   pytest.skip('Test Message')

def test_1(test_me):
   pass
```

Not sure if this is platform-specific, or if it works with OPs configuration, since OP didn't provide any specific info.

Comment: This answers the question.  Thank you.  It worked on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is any built-in way of printing these messages during the test runs. An alternative is to create your own skip function that does this:

```py
def skip(message):
    print(message)  # you can add some additional info around the message
    pytest.skip()

@pytest.fixture()
def test_me():
     if condition:
        skip('Test Message')
```

You could probably turn this custom function into a decorator too.

Answer (score 0):

A cursory look at the code for pytest points to the fact that it becomes wrapped up as the message for the exception that's raised off the back of calling `skip()` itself. Its behavior, while not explicitly documented, is defined in [`outcomes.py`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/f54ec30a6d7969eba6a2003b4409d33828cd406d/src/_pytest/outcomes.py):

```
def skip(msg: str = "", *, allow_module_level: bool = False) -> "NoReturn":
    """Skip an executing test with the given message.
    This function should be called only during testing (setup, call or teardown) or
    during collection by using the ``allow_module_level`` flag.  This function can
    be called in doctests as well.
    :param bool allow_module_level:
        Allows this function to be called at module level, skipping the rest
        of the module. Defaults to False.
    .. note::
        It is better to use the :ref:`pytest.mark.skipif ref` marker when
        possible to declare a test to be skipped under certain conditions
        like mismatching platforms or dependencies.
        Similarly, use the ``# doctest: +SKIP`` directive (see `doctest.SKIP
        <https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html#doctest.SKIP>`_)
        to skip a doctest statically.
    """
    __tracebackhide__ = True
    raise Skipped(msg=msg, allow_module_level=allow_module_level)
```

Eventually, this exception is balled up through several layers and finally thrown as a [`BaseException`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#BaseException). As such, you should be able to access the message itself by trapping the associated exception and reading its exception message ([relevant SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239308/how-to-get-exception-message-in-python-properly/33239954)).