# speech_recognition which worked before throws an error all of a sudden

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I have been working on converting speech to text using `speech_recognition` library on my Jupyter Notebook. All of a sudden, the code throws an error and I have no idea where to even start to solve this. The code is shown below:

```py
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.AudioFile('/audio1659122935.wav') as source:
    audio_text = r.record(source)
    
    try:
        txt = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
        print(text)
    except:
        print('Error... Try again...')
```

This generates the `except` message "`Error... Try again...`"

Did anyone have the same issue with using `speech_recognition`?

The `speech_recognition` version is 3.8.1 and my python version is 3.8.5

Comment: Instead of just `print('Error... Try again...')`, print out the exception/stack trace. [How to get exception message in Python properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33239954)

Comment: Remove (unwrap) the `try: except:`. You can never know what error is happening if you do what you're now doing.

Comment: OMG it was just a simple mistake of using a wrong variable text! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

It was just a simple mistake using the wrong variable text. Also just unwrap the try except clause to see where the error occurs.