# Detect Specific Error Description in Python

Tags: python, math, error-handling

Not sure if it's possible, but I'm wondering if I can get the "specific" error.
I can get an error through

```py
print(ERROR.__name__)
```

and this would return "ZeroDivisionError", but the error message can be different, for example, if I do `int(1) / int(0)` I get "division by zero", but if I do `float(1) / float(0)` I get "float division by zero". I'm wondering how I could make an if statement and detect which one it specifically is.

Comment: [How to get exception message in Python properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33239308/how-to-get-exception-message-in-python-properly)

Answer (score 0):

The float division vs division message is kept in the string representation of the object.
You could simply convert the the object to a string and then check this against the string or you could manually call the `__repr__` method of the exception.

Example:

```
try:
    3 / 0
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e) == 'float division by zero')
```

prints False

```
try:
    3.0 / 0.0
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e) == 'float division by zero')
```

prints True

Comment: I was thinking that, but is this the only way possible?

Comment: @xyz there are ways to access the internal message with getattr but i think this is the most readable way